# How do I increase the loop cut amount on macOS Blender 2.8?

Tags: modeling

How do I increase the loop cut amount on macOS? I have no where in the UI where I can change it.

Mouse wheel doesn't work, page up/down doesn't work, and numbers don't work.

[image: Missing loop cut UI]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to select where you want to loop cut first and click the left mouse button. Then a little menu titled "Loop Cut and Slide" should appear in the lower left corner that allows to adjust the number of cuts. For faster editing you can also use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and the scroll wheel to adjust the number of cuts.

[image]

Comment: The window was minimized. Thanks!